# Age Restricitons on Youtube_dl, get_info, ytsearch100:

Tags: python, nested-lists, youtube-dl

I am using the ytsearch method and have implemented ignoreerrors, skip download, and age limit into my code, but I keep running into the problem:

WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone
ERROR: Sign in to confirm your age
This video may be inappropriate for some users.

and the output does not continue to append to the result variable

here is my code:

```
ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True, 'skipdownload': True, 'age_limit': '15'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info( "ytsearch100:reddit --date 2021", download=False)
    
title = list(map(lambda d: d['title'], result['entries']))
ids = list(map(lambda d: d['id'], result['entries']))
date = list(map(lambda d: d['upload_date'], result['entries']))
channel = list(map(lambda d: d['uploader'], result['entries']))

yt_df = yt_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'title':title,'ids':ids,'channel':channel,'date':date}))
```

and my error is as follows. It appears that there are blank rows in the results dictionary when the error occured. I also tried using my username and password but that did not work either.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/k9/wwjktzjs3lzg4xwn06htpryh0000gn/T/ipykernel_72457/1081526299.py in <module>
      6     result = ydl.extract_info( "ytsearch100:reddit --date 2021 -i -q", download=False)
      7 
----> 8 title = list(map(lambda d: d['title'], result['entries']))
      9 ids = list(map(lambda d: d['id'], result['entries']))
     10 date = list(map(lambda d: d['upload_date'], result['entries']))

/var/folders/k9/wwjktzjs3lzg4xwn06htpryh0000gn/T/ipykernel_72457/1081526299.py in <lambda>(d)
      6     result = ydl.extract_info( "ytsearch100:reddit --date 2021 -i -q", download=False)
      7 
----> 8 title = list(map(lambda d: d['title'], result['entries']))
      9 ids = list(map(lambda d: d['id'], result['entries']))
     10 date = list(map(lambda d: d['upload_date'], result['entries']))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried changing the ydl_opts, making a dataframe from `results['entries']` before subsetting.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the ydl_opts library 'age_limit' needs an int not a string. And using 15 as the age will  definitely not allow age restricted videos.